# how to paste character vector which length more than 1 use glue funcion in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm using the `glue` function to merge 2 character vectors together, but `glue` returns multiple results. I want the `glue` function to return **one result**, but I don't know how. The replicable code is as follows:

```r
library(glue)

a = c('cyl', 'mpg')
b = 'carb'

# glue result

glue("mtcars[{c(a, b)}]")

# mtcars[cyl]
# mtcars[mpg]
# mtcars[carb]

# the result I expected

mtcars[c('cyl', 'mpg', 'carb')]
```

Comment: Take a look at glue_collapse. You’ll probably want to collapse the inner expression first and then join with the outer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @MrFlick you can do this with help of `glue` and `glue_collapse` :

```
library(glue)
glue("mtcars[c(", glue_collapse(glue("{c(a, b)}"), sep = ","), ")]")
#mtcars[c(cyl,mpg,carb)]
```

However, it seems easier using base R :

```
sprintf('mtcars[c(%s)]', toString(c(a, b)))
#[1] "mtcars[c(cyl, mpg, carb)]"
```